# Delete content with a middle line.

Tags: support

I am wondering how can I delete content with a middle line?

I saw it somewhere the other day, but was not able to find it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is just the `<strike>` HTML tag. For example, `<strike> text </strike>` produces  <strike>text</strike> . Note that this only works in questions and answers, not comments.

Comment: In chat, but not comments, you can use ---to strike text---

Comment: And *why* can't you use it in comments? Some of these restrictions are *quite* arbitrary.

Comment: @dfeuer: I see it as a part of comments being "lower status" on the SE network (a principle that the SE team has mentioned, and which I generally agree with). This is how it is explained in [the meta.SO FAQ on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/161783). Other relevant meta.SO threads include [Allow HTML tags in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6407/161783) and [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/161783).

Comment: You can also use just <s>...</s>, which does the same thing.